# XML output wrong encoding format

Tags: c#, xml, umbraco7

I'm fetching an XML feed and getting the wrong character encoding (I think).

The XML feed comes with Scandinavian letters, such as "æøå" and the output doesn't show these, but rather shows them as this: "Ã†Ã" etc.

I'm using XDocument to parse the XML string, and I've given it the following declaration:

```
xDocument.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
```

When I output the XML in my view, I've tried CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as well as Html.Raw etc., but nothing seems to work.

I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Code:

EventArchiveViewModel:

```
public IEnumerable<EventItemViewModel> EventItems
{
    get
    {
        var list = new List<EventItemViewModel>();
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        var xmlString = webClient.DownloadString(EventArchiveModel.XmlFeedUrl);
        var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        xDocument.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        foreach (var item in xDocument.Elements().Descendants("event")) {
            list.Add(new EventItemViewModel(new EventItemModel(item)));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Here's a property in the EventItemModel:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return XmlElement.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault().Value;
    }
}
```

Here's a part of the view:

```
<div class="large-2 medium-6 columns">
   <p class="text-headline_block">
      @item.Name
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The declaration isn't relevant to parsing (parsing a document will create a new one anyway).  Can you give a [mcve] that shows how this problem occurs and where?

Comment: @CharlesMager - thanks for the quick comment, I've updated my question with code. I hope that's better.

Comment: What does `xmlString` look like?  I suspect it is already incorrect by this point.

Comment: @CharlesMager - xmlString looks like this: http://www.thy360.dk/api/d4bd539e-0a9f-4cdb-8ca7-a2e18461d491

Comment: That's what the *source* file looks like.  I'm more interested in what the string looks like in your app after you've downloaded it.  Do these special characters look ok?  I suspect not.

Comment: @CharlesMager - Ahh, sorry.. You're right, the encoding is already wrong in the xmlString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your download.  Per [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) the default encoding for `WebClient` whatever is returned by `Encoding.Default`.

Change this to `Encoding.UTF8` and your string should be decoded correctly. Note there is no need to do anything with XML declarations, this isn't relevant.

```
var webClient = new WebClient
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
};

var xmlString = webClient.DownloadString(EventArchiveModel.XmlFeedUrl);

var doc XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

foreach (var item in doc.Descendants("event")) 
{
   // ...
}
```

You could also remove the step where you download the string by loading the stream straight into the DOM:

```
using (var stream = webClient.OpenRead(EventArchiveModel.XmlFeedUrl))
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
}
```

Comment: I used your first solution, it fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!